# Inverting Laplace transform

Tags: probability, convergence, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

From Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

---

[image]

---

1. Are we allowed to switch derivative and integral as follows:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} e^{-\lambda x} f(x) $$

?

Why/Why not?

---

2. Assuming the $E[f(S_n)]$ equation is true, how does one prove the $f(y)$ equation?

That is, consider $E[f(S_n)]$ as a function of $\lambda$:

$$E[f(S_n)] = E[f(S_n)](\lambda) = \frac{(-1)^n (\lambda)^n L^{n-1}(\lambda)}{(n-1)!}$$

If $\lambda = \frac{n}{y}$, then

$$E[f(S_n)](\frac{n}{y}) = \frac{(-1)^n (\frac{n}{y})^n L^{n-1}(\frac{n}{y})}{(n-1)!}$$

How does one prove that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[f(S_n)](\frac{n}{y}) \left(= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n (\frac{n}{y})^n L^{n-1}(\frac{n}{y})}{(n-1)!} \right) = f(y)?$$

Comment: Cross-posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515987/59351. I've lost count of the number of times I've asked you not to re-post your old questions from *Mathematics* here - would you please stop doing it? It's against [SE policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/225179) (NB "Just to be 100% clear, copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavor" from J.A. himself) & explicitly discouraged on our [help pages](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you've got a question on *Mathematics* you think would benefit from ...

Comment: ... answers with a statistical rather than a mathematical perspective, then when you ask it here you need to adapt it to make that clear & link to the original question. Not linking in particular is discourteous to people who might wish to take into account answers to, comments on, or just the existence of, the original question when deciding if or how to answer its duplicate.

Comment: @Scortchi Very well. Deleted.

Comment: What's deleted? This question & the duplicate on *Mathematics* can't be deleted now because they've already got answers on both sites. For your *other* duplicated questions please decide which site you want them on; or if they've already got answers on both, link to the duplicate (when I or someone else haven't yet added a link in a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1., the interchangeability follows from [the Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Part 2. is tricky, my attempt probably is filled with gaps, but here it is: let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be iid exponential rvs of rate $n/y$, then $S_n\sim\mathrm{Erlang}(n,n/y)$, so $$\varphi_{S_n}(t)=\left(1-\frac{ity}{n}\right)^{-n}$$ But pointwise $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{ity}{n}\right)^{-n}=e^{ity},$$ which means the limiting distribution $S_n\to S$ degenerates at $y$, such that $S$ has Dirac delta as pdf: $$f_S(s)=\delta(s-y).$$ Hence, by [portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), and the fact that $y>0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} E[f(S_n)]=E[f(S)]=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(s)\delta(s-y)\,ds=f(y).$$